past key values from hidden states
I'm trying to extract past key, value pair using attention_layers and hidden_state for a particular layer
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from transformers import LlamaConfig
from transformers import LlamaModel, LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM

tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_to_llama2)

# Load the configuration and enable required outputs
config = LlamaConfig.from_pretrained(path_to_llama2)
config.output_hidden_states = True
config.output_attentions = True  # To get self_attn_weights and biases if needed
config.use_cache = True  # To get past_key_values

model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(path_to_llama2, config=config)

model.eval()

input_text = "Once upon a time"
inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(**inputs)
hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states  # List of hidden states from each layer
state_dict = model.state_dict()

# Function to compute past_key_values for a single layer
def compute_past_key_values_for_layer(layer_idx, hidden_state):
    attention_layers = [layer.self_attn for layer in model.model.layers]
    
    W_q = state_dict[f'model.layers.{layer_idx}.self_attn.q_proj.weight']
    W_k = state_dict[f'model.layers.{layer_idx}.self_attn.k_proj.weight']
    W_v = state_dict[f'model.layers.{layer_idx}.self_attn.v_proj.weight']
    
    queries = torch.matmul(hidden_state, W_q.T)
    keys = torch.matmul(hidden_state, W_k.T)
    values = torch.matmul(hidden_state, W_v.T)

    batch_size, seq_length, hidden_dim = hidden_state.size()
    num_attention_heads = attention_layers[layer_idx].num_heads
    head_dim = hidden_dim // num_attention_heads

    keys = keys.view(batch_size, seq_length, num_attention_heads, head_dim)
    keys = keys.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
    
    values = values.view(batch_size, seq_length, num_attention_heads, head_dim)
    values = values.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
    
    return keys, values

past_key_values = []
for i, hidden_state in enumerate(hidden_states[1:]):  # Skip the embedding layer
    keys, values = compute_past_key_values_for_layer(i, hidden_state)
    past_key_values.append((keys, values))

past_key_values = tuple(past_key_values)

but these past_key_values  don't match with the values I get from outputs.past_key_values for the particular layer.
why's it happening? are there any suggestions?

updated code after applying layernorm and RoPE:
https://pastebin.com/LZXYJAPT
but still the past_key_values are different from the original values obtained using outputs.past_key_values
